# Python : Working with text file OR with list

Tags: python, performance, list, text-files

I am currently working on a script to process some log files (few MB). I am quite new to Python and up to now, my method was to extract some information and pass it to another text file and so on. I would then compare different text files and work that way. Even if I would delete the intermediate text files that I used to get my final output, I found it a bit messy.

As I have started to become more acquainted with lists and I am now trying to use lists instead of text files to store and manage data.

I was wondering what is the best method to use. Should I try to use lists more instead of text files or does that not really matter? I would tend to think lists are better for obvious reasons but I wanted to make sure. I hope it is not too much of a silly question. Thanks

**EDIT**

Quick examples: I would create two text file from the log files and then comparing those text files when now I am doing the same thing with lists

Comment: can you post a simple example of each of your choices?

Comment: You can not use lists INSTEAD OF text files, you may use them TO STORE AND PROCESS DATA from text files

Comment: @Olia Sorry if I did not express myself correctly but that is what I meant. I was basically using my text files to store and process data.

Comment: @16num I added a quick example. Hope it's clear enough

Answer (score 0):

List in python have many methods and features that make it very flexible and manageable.

There are also other types that is similar to lists like generator.

Best of luck.